# ImportError occurs when executing "import Pyfhel"

Tags: python, seal

I have successfully installed Pyfhel-3.4.2. When I executed "import Pyfhel", ImportError occurs. Details: ImportError: /home/username/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Pyfhel/./libAfhel.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK4seal10Ciphertext12save_membersERSo
How could I fix it?

I have re-installed the lib annd checked the depandencies (gcc>=6, python=3.10).